# QMessageBox with link inside, unable to click

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt4.7, qmessagebox

I've already set the `textFormat` to `Qt::RichText`, but the link is still un-clickable.

```
QMessageBox msgBox(this);
msgBox.setWindowTitle(QApplication::applicationName()
                      + " $VER " + QApplication::applicationVersion());
msgBox.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);   //this is what makes the links clickable
msgBox.setText("<a href=\"google.com\">Google</a>");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
msgBox.exec();
```

Any solutions? It's confirmed not working with Qt 4.7.

Comment: How about this one: `"<a href='http://google.com'>Google</a>"` ?

Comment: @Anonymous don't work either .. I really don't know why , it should call xdg-open on Linux

Comment: Do you get any debug output in the console? Does the same happen with a simple standalone code? Is there a desktop environment's file-opener application (`gvfs-open`, `kde-open`, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe this could help QMessageBox.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::LinksAccessibleByMouse);

Answer (score 5):

It is working under mine Qt 4.7.4, albeit I had to modify your `HTML`. Minimal example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setTextFormat(Qt::RichText);   //this is what makes the links clickable
    msgBox.setText("<a href='http://google.com/'>Google</a>");
    msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok);
    msgBox.exec();
    return app.exec();
}
```

If I use this one, the  browser tab is getting opened, and following message ends up in my console:

```
Created new window in existing browser session.
```

If I use your `msgBox.setText` I get error:

```
gvfs-open: file:///tmp/b/google.com: error opening location: Error stating file '/tmp/b/google.com': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried the provided minimal example? Can you click the link? Does anything happen? Anything written to the console (e.g. `Created new window in existing browser session.`)?